# Permutations of iid Random Variables

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable, iid

Suppose that $X_1, X_2, X_3$ are iid random variables. I have seen this fact many times that $$\mathbb{P}(X_1<X_2<X_3)=\frac{1}{6}$$ but I want to know that why every permutation of $X_1, X_2, X_3$ is equally likely and also is this true for both discrete and continuous case and can we generalize this fact for all $n \in \mathbb{N}, n \geq 2$. If yes then how to prove it?

Comment: $\mathbb{P}(X_1<X_2<X_3)=\frac{1}{6}$ is not correct for iid *discrete* random variables, as there is a positive probability of equality, though you would still have $\mathbb{P}(X_1<X_2<X_3)=\mathbb{P}(X_3<X_1<X_2)=\mathbb{P}(X_2<X_1<X_3)$ etc. by symmetry/exchangeability

Comment: $\mathbb{P}(X_1<X_2<X_3)=\frac{1}{6}$ Is it true if $X_1, X_2, X_3$ are iid continuous random variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a matter of notations, nothing more. For instance, define$$Y_1=X_2,Y_2=X_3,Y_3=X_1$$
Then
$$(Y_1,Y_2,Y_3)\sim(X_1,X_2,X_3)$$
(meaning both triplets share the same distribution) and
$$\mathbb{P}(X_1<X_2<X_3)=\mathbb{P}(Y_1<Y_2<Y_3)=\mathbb{P}(X_2<X_3<X_1)$$